# Перегрузка операторов ввода/вывода

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Надо перегрузить операторы ввода/вывода в поток. Пробую так:

```
class Parallelepiped
{
public:
    // ширина
    float width;

    // высота
    float height;

    // длина
    float length;

    float volume() const
    {
        return width * height * length;
    }

    istream& operator>>(istream& in)
    {
        in >> width;
        in >> height;
        in >> length;
        return in;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out) const
    {
        return out << width << height << length;
    }
};
```

И не получается...

Ошибка  C2679   бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Parallelepiped" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Ошибка  C2679   бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Parallelepiped" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Что не так? Видел примеры когда оператор выносится из класса, либо как дружественная функция, но в задании сказано сделать методом.

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/

Comment: @timur вот именно этот пример я и видел. Там как дружественная функция, а не как метод определено.

Comment: В C++ нет методов, если вопрос в терминологии. Приведите [mre] получения этой ошибки

Comment: @dIm0n в смысле нет? Это что-то новенькое. ООП же есть, значит каждая функция внутри класса является методом этого класса. А те функции которые определены снаружи (и не имеют внутри ссылки на `this`) не являются методом. Кажется `friend` тоже методом не будет являться. А насчет примера - вам что мало? Я же привел весь код. Что еще то надо?

Comment: Стандарт называет их "member functions" (функции-члены [класса]), а не "методы". Видимо это имелось в виду.

Comment: Есть функции-члены, а методов нет. Вот я вставил ваш код https://godbolt.org/z/hz59aY и указанной ошибки нет

Comment: @HolyBlackCat окей, это вопрос терминологии. Если говорить с точки зрения ООП то их логичнее называть методами. Я далек от C++, но очень неплохо представляю себе ООП.

Comment: @dIm0n вам правда обязательно вот так докопаться? Вы прекрасно понимаете что надо еще добавить инклуды и main, но вам обязательно мне надо это ткнуть? Я привел минимальный пример и не стал приводить очевидные вещи.

Comment: Ладно инклуды, вы не показали самое главное -- место возникновения ошибки. Для этого и нужен [mre]

Comment: чтобы перегрузить метод ты должен его сначала иметь для перегрузки например он должен быть в родителе объявлен как виртуальный, у тебя класс не является наследником других классов. поэтому и не может перегрузить метод. поэтому и делают через friend-function перегрузку операторов.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Обычно хорошим тоном считается не убирать инклуды и `main`. Здесь проблему можно увидеть и не компилируя код, но если бы проблема была сложнее и нам нужно было бы пробовать компилировать самим, это было бы удобнее делать, если бы из кода не было ничего убрано.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вы все сделали для того, чтобы работал такой код:

```
Parallelepiped p;

p >> cin;
p << cout;
```

Проверьте, убедитесь...

Чтобы работало так, как вы *хотите* - надо объявить операторы *вне* класса:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Parallelepiped& p)
{
    in >> p.width;
    in >> p.height;
    in >> p.length;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Parallelepiped& p)
{
    return out << p.width << p.height << p.length;
}
```

Оператор - член класса требует, чтобы первым в выражении был объект класса.

Comment: Я именно так и делаю. Не компилируется к сожалению.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Ровно так и делаете? `p << cout;`? Не `cout << p;`?

Comment: Да, точно. Ладно, значит придется так как сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК получается, ошибка в "очевидной вещи", а не в "минимальном" примере? :)

Comment: @dIm0n да нету ошибки. Я просто думал что это можно сделать методом, а оказывается нельзя. А код из ответа я сам мог написать. Просто хотел сделать более точно по заданию.

Comment: Перегрузите методами так, чтоб работало `p << cin;` и `p >> cout;` - так оно будет логичнее :)